Replacing sink sprayer in kitchen
`I have been trying to  replace our kitchen sprayer because it is very old and it would not stop leaking, to the point where the water would spray out continuously everywhere. The brand of the faucet is Delta and it is very old. I was able to find a Delta brand sprayer (shown below) but the end of the hose does not fit inside the middle under the sink where it is intended to go. I’m not sure if I need to get another piece that connects the two together or a new hose overall.

Please press the Edit button below your question, and change it: you don't need to apologize or beg for help.  You do need to write a question that describes your actual problem so it can be answered.  A photo of the sprayer and of both ends of its hose would help.

we are here to help. you do not need a plumber for that, is it pull -out sprayer

if it is pull out type, pull it out then hold the hose and unscrew the head (by hand) –

But make sure the water supply valve is turned off first!

Attach a photo by using the "edit" button below your question text, followed by pressing the "moon and mountains" button that appears in the editing window.

Call Delta.  In my experience they have a lifetime guarantee on their faucets and sprayers, and they do stand behind their products.  If you call and explain the issue they are likely to send you wha you need free of charge.  Just ask nicely :)

TL;DR There are multiple "Delta sprayers/hoses" and you need to find an exact match
There are a number (definitely > 1, whether it is 2 or 3 or 10, I don't know) of different attachment mechanisms for the sprayer, even within one brand and faucet type.
In 2018, I purchased a new Delta single-handle kitchen faucet with sprayer from Home Depot. I installed it and found that there was a piece missing so the sprayer would not install properly. I contacted Delta as this was a manufacturing defect and/or packaging issue (the box was factory-sealed when I got it from Home Depot) and so I figured it wasn't really Home Depot's problem. Delta was very responsive and sent me a replacement spray and hose assembly at no charge. But it was the wrong one. Apparently there were two variations at the time for nominally the same faucet model. I can't fault Delta's customer service (that was excellent) but clearly there were problems elsewhere in the company.
So then I went to Home Depot. I explained the problem. They were the epitome of excellence. They took me to the plumbing aisle and started opening boxes until we found the missing (and matching) part. I said "but what about the next person who will need the part" and the answer was something like (it has been 6 years...) "you are the customer that matters right now and we have to make things right".
Took it home. Installed it. Faucet is still working perfectly 6 years later.
If you can't find a good match online, take the existing parts in to your local hardware store. Not Home Depot/Lowes/etc. (even though Home Depot provided great customer service for me, that was to resolve a recent Home Depot purchase, not for replacement parts). Go to the old-fashioned hardware store crowded with parts for everything. They should be able to find you a match.
